OpenAPI Generator & Spring - How to use generated Controllers
When using Spring and OpenAPI Generator, leaving the configuration option interfaceOnly as false results in Controllers being generated.
The OpenAPI Schema does not define an implementation for this method, so, how can these generated Controllers be used? What is their purpose?
OpenAPI Documentation is does not go into into detail regarding this configuration option.

Whether to generate only API interface stubs without the implementation files.


basic idea is following: this option does allow you to test both schema and API client(s) independently from actual server-side implementation, in this case 501 (not implemented) response should be considered as positive, i.e. if you move schema and stubs to separate project (which is actually a good move: since IDEs are unable to generate java classes when building projects based on OpenAPI specs, "green play button" does not work at all, so you are always bound to clean & build lifecycle, which is not so convenient), you need somehow test it.
